# Rails: How to store a value in one place and reference it in others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, constants

I would like to store a value, say the name of my app, in one place (like a constant) and then reference that throughout my app.Therefor if I need to make a global change I can make it in once place and it update throughout my app. Here is one idea on how I can make it work:

**In a constants file**
`APPLICATION_NAME = "FuzzyOnions"`

**In any view I can now reference it like this:**
You are going to love using the `<%= Constants::APPLICATION_NAME %>` application.

The problem I'm running into is when I try to reference it in places such as: `<% @page_title = "<%= Constants::APPLICATION_NAME %> / About" %>` rails throws an error. It also throws an error if I try to reference the constant in a link such as `%= link_to 'Contact Us <%= Constants::APPLICATION_NAME %>', page_path("contact-us") %>`

Is there another way to reference a constant that will not throw an error in these instances? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do to begin with?

Comment: When you say "it throws an error" in a question, it would be *really* helpful if you could show that error. Otherwise, we have a terrible time trying to work out what the error is. The error message is good, but the error message *and the stacktrace* and the related code is best. Please remember to do this in the future, as it will help everyone involved.

Comment: Hey Ryan..thanks for the response. I typically do post the error when I ask a question. For this, I felt like it was going to be one of those "oh yea silly, you can't do that - what are you thinking" obvious type deals. So I took the chance not to clutter the question with the error logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @page_title = "<%= Constants<::APPLICATION_NAME %> / About" %>
```

should be

```
<% @page_title = Constants::APPLICATION_NAME + " / About" %>
```

---

And:

```
<%= link_to 'Contact Us <%= Constants::APPLICATION_NAME %>', page_path("contact-us") %>
```

should be

```
<%= link_to 'Contact Us '+ Constants::APPLICATION_NAME, page_path("contact-us") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a module named YourAppName (whatever that is) in application.rb
This could work:

```
module YourAppName
  class << self
      def [] s
      constants[s]
    end
    def constants
      # you could read this in as a yaml file, cache in a class var, etc.
      {application_name: 'Fuzzy Onions',
       url: 'fuzzy-onions.com'} 
    end




 YourAppName[:application_name]
 => "Fuzzy Onions"  

 AbServ[:url]
 => "fuzzy-onions.com"
```